# How to set correct URL in Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I use Laravel 5 and have the following routing configuration:

```
$router->resource('restaurants', 'Registration');
```

And method:

```
public function store(Auth $userModel, Request $request){
});
```

In my view file I specifed form like:

```
{!! Form::open(array('url' => 'restaurants.store')) !!}
```

When I submit form I am transfered on the address: `restaurants.store` and get error:

Sorry, the page you are looking for could not be found.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the url syntax which needs a slash like so:

```
 {!! Form::open(array('url' => 'restaurants/store')) !!}
```

Or the route syntax (if you've got the route set up) like so:

```
{!! Form::open(array('route' => 'restaurants.store')) !!}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
{!! Form::open(array('url' => route('restaurants.store'))) !!}
```

Answer (score 2):

change `{!! Form::open(array('url' => 'restaurants.store')) !!}` `with {!! Form::open(array('route' => 'restaurants.store')) !!}` and since you use restful, in your routes.php `$router->resource('restaurants', 'RestaurantsController');`